# shift+Arrow keys print ABCD in terminal rather than doing text selection by moving the cursor

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04, I had mistakenly pressed ctrl+A in terminal after that pressing shift+Arrow keys print ABCD based on the direction of arraw keys. How can I get the default behaviour back

Comment: What shell are you using? What is the default behavior that you expect? I don't think Ctrl+A is relevant, the default behavior of `bash` is to print the uppercase ABCD letters.